# How to separate list of programs in html/javascript coming from php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a html/php code as shown below which displays list of links coming from wordpress.

**html/php:**

```
<header class="entry-header container grid-flex">
    <div class="flex-item -sm-50">
        <button>Thumbs</button> // Line Z
    </div>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($all_list); echo "</pre>";   // Line A
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "Active List<br>";
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($active_list); echo "</pre>";   // Line B
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "Passive List<br>";
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($passive_list); echo "</pre>";   // Line C
    // Load the thumbnails view
    get_template_part( 'parts/content-list-thumbs' );     // Line D
    ?>
</div>
```

**Line A** displays following list of links:

```
https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/abcdef/

https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/pdsfhdf

https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/sdfhsw/

https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/dhdhdw/
```

**Line B** displays following links:

```
https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/abcdef/

https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/pdsfhdf
```

**Line C** displays following links:

```
https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/sdfhsw/

https://www.abcd.com/en/programs/dhdhdw/
```

The code inside **content-list-thumbs** file coming from **Line D** is shown below and it is only called on click of a button from **Line Z** in the **html/php** code above.

**html/js code:**

```
<ul id="list-thumbs">
    <?php
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        ?>
        <li class="list-grid__thumb list-grid__item">
            <a class="list-grid__img-link" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_the_permalink()); ?>">
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <?php
                    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
                    CPAC\Images\the_img_fit_figure($image_id, 'list-grid__image', '(min-width: 650px) 50vw, 100vw', false); ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

The above **html/js** code displays list of images associated with Line A.

**Problem Statement:**

What I want to achieve from the **html/js** code above is I want to display list of images associated with **Line B** and **Line C** with a separator.

Line B images

---

Line C images

Comment: How are you getting the lists? Are they posts, pages, just random lists? PS for the future there is WordPress StackOverflow, which would be a better place for this.

Comment: I think they are posts. Check the code  `while (have_posts()) : the_post();` in the html/js code above.

Comment: That line just means while query has data, display for each block this. Assuming B and C are also results of the query, you would need to make a new query call and then pass the data through the same template. Cannot help more unless I see how the lists are generated.